# ffmpeg override the same file for every second of the video

Tags: batch-file, video, ffmpeg

I want to get one image for every 10 seconds from a livestream/video, but the image should have the same name, meaning I want to override it every cycle.

This is my command:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i http://iphone-streaming.ustream.tv/uhls/17074538/streams/live/iphone/playlist.m3u8 -bt 20M -s 480x300 -vf fps=1/10 -y photo.jpg
```

This code works for one image but for the next I get this

> "Could not get frame filename number 2 from pattern 'photo.jpg' (either set updatefirst or use a pattern like %03d within the filename pattern)
>   av_interleaved_write_frame(): Invalid argument"

If I replace photo.jpeg with photo%03d.jpg I get photo001.jpec, followed by photo002.jpeg, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg.exe -i http://iphone-streaming.ustream.tv/uhls/17074538/streams/live/iphone/playlist.m3u8 -s 480x300 -vf fps=1/10 -y -q:v 1 -update 1 photo.jpg
```